# CCTMXTiledMap anchor points of each Tile / CCSprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to set the anchor point of each sprite to the center of the sprite (so 0.5f,0.5f) so when you use the positionAt method for a CCTMXLayer, it actually returns the CGPoint in the middle of the tile ?

I realize I can just do it manually ( and it is what I ll do for now ) by adding half of the x tilesize and half of the y tilesize to the point but I'd like to know if its possible to set it in any way with their API.

What I did try is going through each sprite and settings the anchor point to 0.5,0.5 :

```
for (int i = 0; i < [layer layerSize].width; i++){
   for (int j = 0; j < [layer layerSize].height; j++){
      [[hey tileAt:ccp(i,j)] setAnchorPoint:ccp(0.5f, 0.5f)];
   }
}
```

This (obvs) changed the anchor point of every single tile sprite but when I get the position using positionAt, anchor point 0,0 is still considered.

Again, I could go around this issue and calculate my own center point for each tile, but I would like to know if it is possible to do this without that.

An easy fix would be:

```
CCTMXLayer *layer = [map layerNamed:@...];

-(CGPoint) positionAtFix: (float) x :(float) y {
   CGPoint *abc = ccp([layer positionAt:ccp(x,y)] + [map tileSize].width / 2 ,
                              [layer positionAt:ccp(x,y)] + [map tileSize].height / 2 );
   return abc;
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible without changing the CCTMXTiledMap source code. It was specifically built to render the tiles with anchorPoint at 0,0.

Comment: I'm guessing the same applies to the tiled coord system, which is like the ui touch coord system, as in left top tile is 0,0. this just makes thingy messy !